# Maxscript registeroleinterface appears to not be working

Tags: python, matlab, ole, maxscript

First off, thanks to whoever reads through this and provides me some help/feedback as I have been struggling with this for a couple of days. I am new to stackoverflow and have tried to be as detailed as possible in the question.

I am trying to set up an OLE server on 3ds Max. I have followed the instructions described [here] (http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-AE4CAED2-1EF9-40EF-9761-83F535FE953A.htm,topicNumber=d30e714562) including editing the registry and exposing the function.

However, when I try to call the function from another program (I tried with MATLAB and a python script) I get an error which leads me to suspect that registerOLEInterface is not registering the function. In python, I used a very similar script to the first one [here] (http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?2723-Python-to-MaxScript-to-Python) and get an error like this:

---

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "start.py", line 8, in <module>
maxCOM ._FlagAsMethod("maxCommand")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 437, in _FlagAsMethod
details = build.MapEntry(self.__AttrToID__(name), (name,))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 442, in __AttrToID__ 
return self._oleobj_.GetIDsOfNames(0,attr) pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352570, 'Unknown name.', None, None)`
```

---

In MATLAB, h = actxserver('Max.Application.15') works fine, but when I try to access the function using h.maxCommand, I get this error:

---

```
`No appropriate method, property, or field maxCommand for class COM.Max_Application_15.`
```

---

I would appreciate any help as to what I might be doing wrong. I am using Max 2013 and have tried with 32 and 64-bit versions.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you Register the COM server via the utilities panel in max?
Utilities Panel > Com/DCOM Server Control > Register

Comment: Thanks! This actually solves the problem (at least partly) because I can now get the function to execute from python. However, MATLAB, which I would ideally prefer to use is still giving the same error. I can't seem to vote up your comment for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I don't have access to 3DS Max, and my answer is based on my experience connecting to other OLE and COM Servers from MATLAB (such as Microsoft Office, and OPC servers).

I would be fairly sure that if `h = actxserver('Max.Application.15')` is working fine and doesn't give you an error message, then you have successfully set up and connected to an OLE server.

The problem is more likely to be that you are using an incorrect syntax for whatever the `maxCommand` does in 3DS Max. Perhaps, for example, it requires an input argument. Note that the MATLAB error message is a bit elliptical - it says that there is no *appropriate* method, property or field, not that there is no method, property, or field. I've found that a common reason for getting this message is that I am calling a method that does exist, but not calling it in the right way.

To find out what syntax `maxCommand` is expecting, try typing `methodsview(h)`. This will give you a list of all the methods of `h`, along with their expected input types, and may give you a hint about how `maxCommand` expects to be called.

Hope that helps - I'm afraid there's not much more I can do without access to a copy of 3DS Max.

**EDIT**

Having taken a quick look at the 3DS Max documentation link you provided, it looks like there's a simple function `maxVersion` that doesn't require any input arguments, and just returns you the version number of 3DS Max. Try running `h.maxVersion` as a simple test, to see whether you have successfully connected to a server while avoiding any potential confusions about input arguments to `maxCommand`.

Comment: h.maxVersion is giving the same error. I had tried h.methods previously and the function I defined in Maxscript does not come up, which is why I suspect its interface is not being exposed as it should be (by registerOLEInterface). Thanks

Comment: I suppose since the python script works, it IS being registered and I'm just not accessing it correctly from MATLAB. However, I also tried `h.interfaces` per [this] (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/getting-interfaces-to-the-object.html#f103036) and nothing is returned (not even an error)